# In MS x64 Calling convention, is creating a shadow space necessity for WinAPI calls?

Tags: c++, assembly, 64-bit, win64

In MS x64 calling convention I am reading that caller should create a shadow space if we make calls to a Win64 API.

However I created a simple C++ program and making call to MessageBox and after disassembling this is what I see :

```
00007FF614FC2AD9  mov         r9d,136h  
00007FF614FC2ADF  lea         r8,[__xt_z+150h (07FF614FD5BF0h)]  
00007FF614FC2AE6  lea         rdx,[__xt_z+170h (07FF614FD5C10h)]  
00007FF614FC2AED  xor         ecx,ecx  
00007FF614FC2AEF  call        qword ptr [__imp_MessageBoxW (07FF614FDF6C0h)]  
00007FF614FC2AF5  mov         dword ptr [msgboxID],eax
```

I don't see any Shadow space reservation.(Not even in the preceding instructions that are not shown here) What am I missing ?

Edit: Here is the C++ code for above:

```
  #include <Windows.h>


   int main()
   {
        int msgboxID = MessageBox(
        NULL,
        (LPCWSTR) L"Resource not available\nDo you want to try again?",
        (LPCWSTR) L"Account Details",
        MB_ICONWARNING | MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE | MB_DEFBUTTON2
        );
     return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Some APi calls modify the arguments that are passed to them, string buffers in particular If you want to preserve those values you need to make a copy of them before calling those functions. Unless you have _explicitly_ created a copy you won't see it in the disassembly. Why do you think the compiler would do that for you?

Comment: Maybe show the whole function?

Comment: I don't think the questions are the same. I am merely pointing out that the documentation says so, but the compiler generated code doing otherwise. And trying to figure out if this is legimate.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it does generate shadow space. But at the very beginning of the call.(not shown above stack) I thought it would create shadow space just before the call apparently that is not the case.
So I will close this question and open a more proper one.